# How to include compiled GameMonkey script in final game release instead of script source?

Tags: scripting, release

I use GameMonkey to script the game play and use the script from my C\C++ host game.
I've got it working the script with my engine.
But I have a question. In these engines like Torque, Unreal, Unity, etc. when you finally build the game, all the scripts are also compiled and you don't need to ship all the script source.

How do I do that?
Right now my engine needs GameMonkey source script to process the game logic.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the GameMonkey forum

> You want to gmMachine::CompileStringToLib() and later ExecuteLib(). You will want to do that  with SetDebugMode() disabled otherwise your source code will be included in the compiled library.

http://www.somedude.net/gamemonkey/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=555&hilit=compile